# Is there armasm on mac?

Tags: macos, assembly, arm, gnu-assembler, armasm

I just started to learn ARM assembly and I know that there are mainly two toolchains to assemble ARM assembly, armasm and gnu. I am not able to use KEIL/IAR since I am using mac. Is there anyway I can add the armasm assembler to some IDEs on mac? I currently have vscode, stm32cube,and segger embedded studio.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using Segger Embedded Studio, I'm afraid I don't quite understand your question.

That is: You don't need to install any additional assembler with that IDE, for it already comes with three assemblers by default: GNU, Clang, as well as SEGGER's own assembler (beta version). You can select the assembler to use inside the project options.